# How can I get the keyboard to display with my UITextField in my UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a `UITextField` in a `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`. All of these are defined in Interface Builder. The `UITableView` is hooked up to a `UITableViewController` and is set as its datasource and delegate. The `UITextField` is referenced via an `IBOutlet`/property `textEmail`. All of this is inside of a tabbed view if that matters. User Interaction is enabled for all of these.

Everything displays fine, but the keyboard does not show up when the `UITextField` is selected. I can see that `textFieldDidBeginEditing` gets called, but no keyboard. I've tried putting a call to `becomeFirstResponder` in `viewWillAppear` and it gets called, but still no keyboard:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"View will appear");
    [textEmail becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

I've also tried putting the call directly in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` and also in an `IBAction` connected to a touch event with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Do you only have only one custom tableviewcell at a time? If so, it would be much easier to not use a tableview for what you are trying to do.

If you have multiple cells (or one cell), then you need to make sure your class is a UITextFieldDelegate. Then in your cellForRowAtIndexPath function get the current textfield and assign the delegate of the textField to self.

Then add the following function to your implementation:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField 
{
     [textField becomeFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: I probably should've explicitly specified that I did implement `UITextFieldDelegate` but as my original post states, I've tried putting `becomeFirstResponder` in `textFieldDidBeginEditing` already. I do have multiple custom cells but only one of this particular type. I've also already set the `delegate` of the `UITextField` to the `UITableViewController`.